# Django-tinymce {#advanced_dlg.link_title}

Tags: python, django, tinymce

In my Django blog, I get the following empty pop-up

[image: Empty popup]

when I click on the `link` button in the `TinyMCE` editor.
[image]

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably you gave a link to button like ‘#’ and give it a command to open new popup or blank page! So just vheck the link setting there!